# NullReferenceException on trying to enumerate an empty IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I am getting a NullReferenceException when I try and convert the following LINQ to EF query.  What could be wrong here?

```
            List<DailyProductionRecord> prodRecs = new List<DailyProductionRecord>();
            var recs = from p in productionEntities.DailyProductionRecordSet
                       where ((p.Department.DeptId == dept.DeptId) && (p.RecordDate >= thisPeriodStart) && (p.RecordDate < nextPeriodStart))
                       select p;
            prodRecs = recs.ToList();
```

**EDIT:** I've just discovered I was too quick off the mark, and my dept criterion was null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is p.Department can be null?

Comment: Not quite, but dept is null.  Close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from accessing properties on objects that can be null (`p.Department` and `dept` can both be null), you are also instantiating a new `List<DailyProductionRecord>` that never gets used. So your example can be written like this:

```
List<DailyProductionRecord> prodRecs = (from p in productionEntities.DailyProductionRecordSet
                                        where ((p.Department.DeptId == dept.DeptId) && (p.RecordDate >= thisPeriodStart) && (p.RecordDate < nextPeriodStart))
                                        select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronald, but that's how I started off.  If was just decomposing this when I used the extra list.